# How to cite three things in the same sentence

Tags: citations

If all A, B, and C are from the same reference [1], what is the shortest way to cite them? Is this clear?

> I use A, B, and C [1] in my paper.

It is concise, but it is like you are not giving a reference for A, and B. How can I have a better sentence?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The original "I use A, B, and C [1] in my paper." is not quite clear for the reasons you've mentioned.

Better:

> I use A, B, and C in my paper [1].

Comment: How about this?: I use A, B, and C [1] in my paper.

Comment: How is my suggestion?